# How to insert component inside <td> on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm facing a problem with inserting React Component in td tag. This component should be inserted in that td which was clicked.

As you can see every td has **onClick** event listener for **checkPlayer** function. This function checks value of **sign state** and depends on that value X component or O component will be inserted in that specific td.

Can you guys please help me how to render components like this? Current approach only write **[object object]**

**My goal - output**

```
<td>{<X />}</td>
```

**X component ,O component is pretty much same**

```
import React from 'react';

//styles
import './X.scss';

function X(){
    return(
        <div className="X">
            <p>X</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default X;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [sign,setSign] = useState(true)
  function checkPlayer(e){

    //1st player
    if(sign === true){
      e.target.innerHTML = <X />;
      
      setSign(false);
    }
      
    //2nd player
    if(sign === false){
      e.target.innerText = <O />;

      setSign(true);
    }
}
```

**HTML part of App.js**

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
              <td onClick={checkPlayer}></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This approach is non-React. What you do instead is 1) keep an array in state that stores the nine fields (blank, X or O) 2) have `checkPlayer` update the array (and rename the function to `handleClick` or something similar to indicate what it actually does) 3) render the state using basic React list rendering

Comment: Here's the basic idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-worker-zp695?file=/src/App.js (this shows list rendering using `.map()` and how to update a multi-dimensional array)

Comment: thank you but im not that far in react.  I dont really get what u did there

Comment: There must be some simple way.. not using matrix like you

Comment: Nope, not really. You could use a simple array with nine elements though. Tic Tac Toe means you have to check for three-in-a-row, a matrix makes that much simpler.

Comment: `a ? b : c` is called a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator); it's value depends on `a` being truthy or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I played around with it, this should give you a good direction to go. (note: you need to use [...values] to create a new array instead of referencing the old one so that the UI rerenders).

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [sign,setSign] = useState(true);

  const [values, setValues] = useState([["", " ", " "],[" ", " ", " "],[" ", " ", " "]]);

  function updateValue(row, column){
      var newValue = [...values];
      newValue[row][column] = sign == true ? "X" : "O";
      setSign(!sign);
      setValues(newValue);
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(0,0)}>{values[0][0]}</td>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(0,1)}>{values[0][1]}</td>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(0,2)}>{values[0][2]}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(1,0)}>{values[1][0]}</td>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(1,1)}>{values[1][1]}</td>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(1,2)}>{values[1][2]}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(2,0)}>{values[2][0]}</td>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(2,1)}>{values[2][1]}</td>
              <td onClick={() => updateValue(2,2)}>{values[2][2]}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you very much. can you please explain me more this line? 

newValue[row][column] = nextIsX == true ? "X" : "O";

I dont really get that from  = nextIsX == true ? "X" : "O";

Comment: ,please i need more help

Comment: You are not creating a deep copy of the `values` array and thus mutating state. And handcoding the JSX like that is bad practice all around. See my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-worker-zp695?file=/src/App.js) for the correct way to do this.

Comment: It's an "if" statement condensed down to one line. "condition ? "value if true" : "value if false"

Comment: @ChrisG does have a more clean and concise version. If you're not familiar with .map, it might be more difficult to follow. Either way, I'd check out his version and see if you can follow the logic. Good stuff to know.